# Reset the day of each month

Tags: python

I have a column of a dataframe that looks like:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2017-05-13 |
| 2017-05-13 |
| 2017-05-13 |
| 2017-05-14 |
| 2017-05-14 |
| 2017-05-15 |
| 2017-07-02 |
| 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-07-03 |
| 2017-07-04 |
| 2018-01-14 |

I want to reset the day of each month:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2017-05-01 |
| 2017-05-01 |
| 2017-05-01 |
| 2017-05-02 |
| 2017-05-02 |
| 2017-05-03 |
| 2017-07-01 |
| 2017-07-02 |
| 2017-07-02 |
| 2017-07-03 |
| 2018-01-01 |

So each month should start by the first day of the day of the month. Days always follow each others.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split dates by month, and after that, you have to get the day list by the set index, with the index you add it at the end of the string

```
def transformDates(dates : list):

    #sorting
    dates = sorted(dates) 

    date_dict = {}

    for date in dates:
        #month key
        month = date.split("-")[1] #get the month number to be used as dict key

        #add the date in their respective lists
        #there will be one list for each month
        if month not in date_dict:
            date_dict[month] = [date]
        else:
            date_dict[month] += [date]
    
    
    #date_dict -> {
    #'05': ['2017-05-13', '2017-05-13', '2017-05-13', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-15'], 
    #'07': ['2017-07-02', '2017-07-03', '2017-07-03', '2017-07-04'], 
    #'01': ['2018-01-14']
    #} - Splitting by month

    for month_key in date_dict:

        #Get the list of each month without duplication
        units = sorted(list(set(date_dict[month_key].copy())))
        
        #'05': ['2017-05-13', '2017-05-13', '2017-05-13', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-15']
        # -> ['2017-05-13', '2017-05-13', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-15']
        #Each possition is the number of the ording -1 (due array index starts by 0)
        
        for i in range(len(units)):

            for j in range(len(date_dict[month_key])):

                day_str = "0" + str(i+1) if i < 10 else i+1 #add 1 to the day -> postion 0 to day 1 (position + 1 -> day)
                #transforming
                if units[i] == date_dict[month_key][j]:
                    #concat the 8 first letters "2017-05-" (date_dict[month_key][j][0:8]) with the day ordering
                    date_dict[month_key][j] = date_dict[month_key][j][0:8] + day_str
                    continue

    #concat all the dates and sort them
    dates = sorted([date for month in date_dict for date in date_dict[month]])              
    
    return dates

dates = [
    "2017-05-13",
    "2017-05-13",
    "2017-05-13",
    "2017-05-14",
    "2017-05-15",
    "2017-05-14",
    "2017-07-02",
    "2017-07-03",
    "2017-07-03",
    "2017-07-04",
    "2018-01-14"]

transformDates(dates)
```

Result:

```
['2017-05-01',
 '2017-05-01',
 '2017-05-01',
 '2017-05-02',
 '2017-05-02',
 '2017-05-03',
 '2017-07-01',
 '2017-07-02',
 '2017-07-02',
 '2017-07-03',
 '2018-01-01']
```

Comment: I'd recommend using replace for datetime types, you can simple replace the date (year/month/day/...) with any given value

Comment: There's an error at '2017-07-01', '2017-07-01', '2017-07-02' result, I'm in class right now, when I'm done, I can fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much @NatanAlmeidadeLima , I am waiting for your fix, could you also add a little more explanation to the function?

Comment: Sure. I've fixed the problem. Check it now ;)

Comment: @AlejandroA. Thank you for your feedback. I considered as a String for example level, but you're right. In the case of datetime, it is "date.replace(days=int(day_str))"

Comment: @NewJ there's is still another error xD at line: "month = date.split("-")[1]" will group by month independently on the year, you just have to make the variable month receive the year and month, like -> 2020-10-14 to 2020_10

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Given the dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': [
    "2017-05-13",
    "2017-05-13",
    "2017-05-13",
    "2017-05-14",
    "2017-05-15",
    "2017-05-14",
    "2017-07-02",
    "2017-07-03",
    "2017-07-03",
    "2017-07-04",
    "2018-01-14"]})
data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Dates'])
data['Month_Dates'] = data['Dates'].dt.month
```

You can group by date, resample per months (we want to work with months) and take the 0nth result (first available day).

Then I build a dict with the original date as key, and the replaced date (using dt.replace) and remap:

```
first_days=data.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Dates']).to_period('M'),as_index=False).nth(0)

replace_dict = dict(zip(first_days['Dates'], first_days['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))))
data['Dates'].replace(replace_dict)
```

Result:

```py
0    2017-05-01
1    2017-05-01
2    2017-05-01
3    2017-05-14
4    2017-05-15
5    2017-05-14
6    2017-07-01
7    2017-07-03
8    2017-07-03
9    2017-07-04
10   2018-01-01
```

**Note: Code is quite ugly, can be improved.**

Comment: Hello, thank you but every day of the dataframe is replaced by 01. I need to find a way to 'reset' the day counter.

Comment: @NewJ Ah sorry! I would go something like finding the max date per every month and replacing the day for 01 as I mentioned, I do not have time right now might take a look later

Comment: @NewJ Not sure if that's what you want with the last edit

Comment: Thank you but there is still a little mistake in the final result (2017-05-14), I will look at your code since it seems easier to understand.